# How to get the count of a specif value from a single column

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, count

I was working with a project where I want to get the count of values in a column. I will explain with an example. 
I have a table column named name. Where it's values are A,B,C,D,A,D,B,A,C.
 Now I want the output as

```
Count: A-3,B-2,C-2,D-2.
```

I have tried using group by and distinct. but both don't give me what I want. It all getting the total count of that item. In the code given below is the query I tried. There I want the count of `particulars_id` and the `$public_page_id` will be common for all `particulars_id` I am fetching. There will be a number of `public_page_id` in the table, and each will have some `particulars_id` under them.

```
    $output = '';
    $this->db->select('COUNT(service_appointment_details.particulars_id) 
    as count,particulars.particulars_name');
    $this->db->from('particulars');
    $this->db->group_by('particulars.particulars_id');
    $this->db->where('particulars.public_page_id',$public_page_id);
    $this->db- 
    >join('service_appointment_details','particulars.public_page_id = 
    service_appointment_details.public_page_id','right');
    $this->db->where($where_date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

### Expected Result

Expected Result is (based on the above example)

```
Count: A-3,B-2,C-2,D-2.
```

### Actual Result

But what I'm getting now is

```
Count: A-9,B-9,C-9,D-9.
```

I need to fetch count of each `particulars_id` under the given `public_page_id`

Comment: Do you have 9 rows in `service_appointment_details` or in `particulars`?Did you try `inner join`?

Comment: This is just an example. Actually, I'm having 3 `particular_id`. Among these three, one has two rows and one has 1 row. 3rd one doesn't have any row for now. so the output should display count as `row1-2 row2-1 row3-0`

Answer (score 0):

You should use count(*)

```
 $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count,particulars.particulars_name');
 ........
```

Comment: This changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @scaisEdge, you need to use `count(*)` instead of `count(service_appointment_details.particulars_id)`. By using `count(service_appointment_details.particulars_id)`, you basically count the number of rows from your select which is not what you want.

Final snippet would be:

```
$output = '';
$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count, particulars.particulars_name');
$this->db->from('particulars');
$this->db->group_by('particulars.particulars_name');
$this->db->where('particulars.public_page_id',$public_page_id);
$this->db->join('service_appointment_details','particulars.public_page_id = service_appointment_details.public_page_id','right');
$this->db->where($where_date);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Whenever you want to count occurrence of a column values, you'd do

```
SELECT column_to_count, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY column_to_count
```

Comment: You mentioned `By using count(service_appointment_details.particulars_id), you basically count the number of rows from your select`. This is what I want. I don't want the total count. Anyway code you have given also produced the same result as mine.

Comment: So what you're looking for is the number of `particulars_id` per `name`?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I will have a `public_page_id` in the where condition. Each `public_page_id` will have a set of `particulars_id`(In the table, there will be a number of `public_page_ids`). So what I want is the count of each `particular_id` under the `public_page_id` in where clause.